# Javascript and Multiple Check All boxes

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfc

I an having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to have multiple check all boxes work on the same page. We have had developers over the years build and add to the code.

But what this is meant to do is have one report of users and a check box next to the beginning of each row. These boxes can be checked to add multiple users to a temporary group. But at the top there is checkbox that acts as a check all box.

The dilemma is I have created multiple groups of users. The top check all box as you can imagine checks all the user boxes. What I would like to do is have the top check all box check the boxes for just that section.

Here's an example of what it looks like:

[image]

The problem is I am not that good at javascript but have spent hours trying to work with the code to have just Accepted/Confirm SMS check all box check the boxes below it. And so forth.

Here is the code for the Accepted/Confirm SMS section:

```
<!--- now, render the results table heading --->        
<table id="results" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rowSelect" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <cfif This.CanManageUsers or This.CanSendAlerts>
            <th id="addToAddHoc"><cfset adHocGroupRenderer.RenderCheckAll()></th>
        </cfif>
        <!---<th width="100">Positions</th>--->
        <th width="75">Response</th>

        <th width="100">First Name</th>
        <th width="100">Last Name</th>
        <th width="280"><cfif session.view_users>
            Phone Number
        <cfelse>
        N/A
        </cfif>
        Carrier</th>
        <th class="nw">Message Sent</th>
        <th class="nw">Reply Received</th>
    </tr>
    <cfloop from = "1" to = "#get_messages_accept.RecordCount#" index = "i">
        <cfif IsDate(get_messages_accept.message_date[i])>
            <cfset get_messages_accept.message_date[i] = Application.TimeZoneConverter.convertTime(ParseDateTime(get_messages_accept.message_date[i]), 'dbToLocal', This.TimeZone) />
        </cfif>

        <cfset subscriber = Application.provider.GetSubscriber(get_messages_accept.sub_id[i]) />
        <tr>
            <cfif This.CanManageUsers or This.CanSendAlerts>
                <td><cfset adHocGroupRenderer.RenderCheckbox(get_messages_accept.sub_id[i])></td>
            </cfif>
            <!---<td>#i#</td>--->
            <td><font color="##4DA019"><img src="../../imgs/new/thumb_up.png" width="20"> #UCASE(get_messages_accept.sms_reply[i])#</font></td>
            <td><font color="##4DA019">#subscriber.FirstName#</font></td>
            <td><font color="##4DA019">#subscriber.LastName#</font></td>
            <td class="nw" width="280"><cfif session.view_users>
                <cfif IsNumeric(get_messages_accept.dest[i])>#subscriber.ConvertToHtml(Settings, get_messages_accept.dest[i], (This.CanManageUsers or This.CanSendAlerts))#<cfelse>N/A</cfif>/
            </cfif>
            #get_messages_accept.carrier_title[i]#</td>
            <td class="nw">
                #DateFormat(get_messages_accept.message_date[i],"m/d/yyyy")#&nbsp;
                #TimeFormat(get_messages_accept.message_date[i],"h:mm:sstt")#
            </td>
            <td class="nw">
                #DateFormat(get_messages_accept.sms_reply_time[i],"m/d/yyyy")#&nbsp;
                #TimeFormat(get_messages_accept.sms_reply_time[i],"h:mm:sstt")#
            </td>
        </tr>
    </cfloop>               
</table>
```

Here is the code for Accepted/Confirmed Voice

```
<div id="actions">
    <img src="../../imgs/new/phone.png" width="25"> Accepted/Confirmed Voice
</div>


<!--- now, render the results table heading --->        
<table id="results" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rowSelect" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <cfif This.CanManageUsers or This.CanSendAlerts>
            <th id="addToAddHoc"><cfset adHocGroupRenderer.RenderCheckAll()></th>
        </cfif>
        <!---<th width="100">Positions</th>--->
        <th width="75">Response</th>
        <th width="100">First Name</th>
        <th width="100">Last Name</th>  
        <cfif session.view_users>
            <th width="280">Phone</th>
        </cfif>


        <th class="nw">Message Sent</th>
        <th class="nw">Reply Received</th>
    </tr>
    <cfloop from = "1" to = "#get_messages_accept_voice.RecordCount#" index = "i">
        <cfif IsDate(get_messages_accept.message_date[i])>
            <cfset get_messages_accept.message_date[i] = Application.TimeZoneConverter.convertTime(ParseDateTime(get_messages_accept.message_date[i]), 'dbToLocal', This.TimeZone) />
        </cfif>

        <cfset subscriber = Application.provider.GetSubscriber(get_messages_accept_voice.sub_id[i]) />
        <tr>
            <cfif This.CanManageUsers or This.CanSendAlerts>
                <td><cfset adHocGroupRenderer.RenderCheckbox(get_messages_accept_voice.sub_id[i])></td>
            </cfif>
            <!---<td>#i#</td>--->
            <td><font color="##4DA019"><img src="../../imgs/new/thumb_up.png" width="20"> #UCASE(get_alert.accept_resp)#</font></td>
            <td><font color="##4DA019">#subscriber.FirstName#</font></td>
            <td><font color="##4DA019">#subscriber.LastName#</font></td>
            <cfif session.view_users>
                <td class="nw" width="280">#get_messages_accept_voice.dest[i]#</td>
            </cfif>


            <td class="nw">
                #DateFormat(get_messages_accept_voice.message_date[i],"m/d/yyyy")#&nbsp;
                #TimeFormat(get_messages_accept_voice.message_date[i],"h:mm:sstt")#
            </td>                       
            <td class="nw">
                #DateFormat(get_messages_accept_voice.message_date[i],"m/d/yyyy")#&nbsp;
                #TimeFormat(get_messages_accept_voice.message_date[i],"h:mm:sstt")#
            </td>
        </tr>
    </cfloop>               
</table>
```

So what the file references at the top is basic include:

```
<cfset var adHocGroupRenderer = Application.ComponentFactory.CreateAdHocGroupRenderer() />
```

And here is the functions that are referenced:

```
<cffunction name="RenderCheckbox" access="public" returntype="void" hint="Renders a Subscriber checkbox." output="true">
    <cfargument name="subscriberID" type="numeric" required="yes" hint="The subscriber ID to render checkbox for.">
    <cfoutput>
        <input type="checkbox" value="#subscriberID#" name="subscriberID" class="selectRow" />
    </cfoutput>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="RenderCheckAll" access="public" returntype="void" hint="Renders the check all checkbox." output="true">
    <cfoutput>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAllSubscriberIDs" name="checkAllSubscriberIDs" />
    </cfoutput>
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="RenderActions" access="public" returntype="void" hint="Renders the action buttons (at the beginning just add button)." output="true">     
    <cfoutput>
        <div id="adHocGroupActions">
            <input type="button" name="addToAdHocGroupButton" value="Add to Temporary Group" id="addToAdHocGroupButton" />
            <span id="adHocGroupAddStatus"></span>
        </div>
    </cfoutput>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="RenderScript" access="public" returntype="void" hint="Renders the javascript needed." output="true">      
    <cfoutput>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/adHocGroup.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var adHocGroup = new adHocGroup();
        </script>
    </cfoutput>
</cffunction>
```

I know the answer is in here somewhere but I just can't figure it out.

Here is the source code from the browser once it's built:

```
<div id="actions">
    <img src="../../imgs/new/sms.png" width="25"> Accepted/Confirmed SMS 
</div>




        <table id="results" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rowSelect" width="100%">
            <tr>

                    <th id="addToAddHoc"> 
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAllSubscriberIDs" name="checkAllSubscriberIDs" />
    </th>


                <th width="75">Response</th>

                <th width="100">First Name</th>
                <th width="100">Last Name</th>
                <th width="280">
                    Phone Number

                Carrier</th>
                <th class="nw">Message Sent</th>
                <th class="nw">Reply Received</th>
            </tr>

                <tr>

                        <td> 
        <input type="checkbox" value="5364603" name="subscriberID" class="selectRow" />
    </td>


                    <td><font color="#4DA019"><img src="../../imgs/new/thumb_up.png" width="20"> CONFIRM</font></td>
                    <td><font color="#4DA019">Sterling</font></td>
                    <td><font color="#4DA019">Archer</font></td>
                    <td class="nw" width="280"> <a href="https://new.wensnetwork.com/users/editusers.cfm?sub_id=5364603" title="View account details for Sterling Archer"> 3305555555 </a>&nbsp;/
                    Verizon Wireless</td>
                    <td class="nw">
                        3/29/2020&nbsp;
                        6:28:05PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="nw">
                        3/29/2020&nbsp;
                        6:28:17PM
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                        <td> 
        <input type="checkbox" value="9092536" name="subscriberID" class="selectRow" />
    </td>


                    <td><font color="#4DA019"><img src="../../imgs/new/thumb_up.png" width="20"> CONFIRM</font></td>
                    <td><font color="#4DA019">Alec</font></td>
                    <td><font color="#4DA019">Smith</font></td>
                    <td class="nw" width="280"> <a href="https://new.wensnetwork.com/users/editusers.cfm?sub_id=9092536" title="View account details for Alec Dettling"> 3305555555 </a>&nbsp;/
                    Verizon Wireless</td>
                    <td class="nw">
                        3/29/2020&nbsp;
                        6:28:05PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="nw">
                        3/29/2020&nbsp;
                        8:09:07PM
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                        <td> 
        <input type="checkbox" value="10504336" name="subscriberID" class="selectRow" />
    </td>


                    <td><font color="#4DA019"><img src="../../imgs/new/thumb_up.png" width="20"> CONFIRM</font></td>
                    <td><font color="#4DA019">Ashley</font></td>
                    <td><font color="#4DA019">Jones</font></td>
                    <td class="nw" width="280"> <a href="https://new.wensnetwork.com/users/editusers.cfm?sub_id=10504336" title="View account details for Ashley Jones">3305555555</a>&nbsp;/
                    Verizon Wireless</td>
                    <td class="nw">
                        3/29/2020&nbsp;
                        6:28:05PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="nw">
                        3/29/2020&nbsp;
                        7:50:57PM
                    </td>
                </tr>

        </table>

        <div id="actions">
            <img src="../../imgs/new/phone.png" width="25"> Accepted/Confirmed Voice
        </div>



        <table id="results" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rowSelect" width="100%">
            <tr>

                    <th id="addToAddHoc"> 
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAllSubscriberIDs" name="checkAllSubscriberIDs" />
    </th>


                <th width="75">Response</th>
                <th width="100">First Name</th>
                <th width="100">Last Name</th>  

                    <th width="280">Phone</th>



                <th class="nw">Message Sent</th>
                <th class="nw">Reply Received</th>
            </tr>

                <tr>

                        <td> 
        <input type="checkbox" value="3981337" name="subscriberID" class="selectRow" />
    </td>


                    <td><font color="#4DA019"><img src="../../imgs/new/thumb_up.png" width="20"> CONFIRM</font></td>
                    <td><font color="#4DA019">Scott</font></td>
                    <td><font color="#4DA019">dfwefwew</font></td>

                        <td class="nw" width="280">3302895161</td>



                    <td class="nw">
                        3/29/2020&nbsp;
                        6:28:13PM
                    </td>                       
                    <td class="nw">
                        3/29/2020&nbsp;
                        6:28:13PM
                    </td>
                </tr>

        </table>
```

I know its a lot to review but I'm hoping it is something simple I am missing. Any suggestions or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I will give you enough so you can learn how to fish, so-to-speak. First you need a high level of control in JavaScript in order to know what is going on *event wise*:

```
var option = {};

window.onclick = function(event)
{
 option.click = event.target;

 if (event.target.nodeName == 'input' && event.target.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox')
 {
  //See notes from this point.
 }
}
```

Now software varies greatly. In my case I'd simply use `push_current_id()` to get the id of the current page, iterate over `id_(push_current_id()).tag_('form')` until I found `is_node_parent(event.target,id_(push_current_id()).tag_('form')[i])`. Here is that function:

```
function is_node_parent(node_find,node_parent)
{
 var nf = false;
 var nc = false;
 var error = false;

 if (typeof node_find=='string')
 {
  if (id_(node_find)) {nf = id_(node_find);}
  else {error = 'Developer Error: you must first verify that the node_find id '+node_find+' exists before calling is_node_parent().';}
 }
 else {nf = node_find;}

 if (typeof node_parent=='string')
 {
  if (id_(node_parent)) {nc = id_(node_parent);}
  else {error = 'Developer Error: you must first verify that the node_parent id '+node_parent+' exists before calling is_node_parent().';}
 }
 else {nc = node_parent;}

 if (error) {dialog.alert(error);}
 else if (is_not_null(nf) && is_not_null(nc) && nc.compareDocumentPosition)
 {
  try {var r = nc.compareDocumentPosition(nf);}
  catch (e)
  {
   if (arguments.callee.caller.toString())
   {
    var f = arguments.callee.caller.toString();

    if (f.split('function ')[1])
    {
     f = f.split('function ')[1];

     if (f.split('(')[0]) {f = f.split('(')[0];}
    }
   }
   else {f = 'unknown';}

   report_bug('is_node_parent','Called by '+f+'(); '+e+'.');
  }

  r = (r==20 || r==0) ? true : false;
 }
 else
 {
  console.log(is_node_parent.arguments.callee.caller.toString().split('function '));
  dialog.alert('Error: is_node_parent error, find: '+node_find+', node_parent = '+node_parent+'.');
 }

 return r;
}
```

Here you can extend the DOM (e.g. how I use `id_().tag_()`):

```
Object.prototype.tag_ = function(t) {return (this.getElementsByTagName && this.getElementsByTagName(t) && this.getElementsByTagName(t).length > 0) ? this.getElementsByTagName(t) : false;}
```

So with this code you're iterating over each `form` element trying to see (from within `window.onclick` event handler) if the `form[i]` is the `parentNode` that contains the *clicked element* (`event.target`).

Once you find that element then you simply iterate over all of the inputs that have `.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox'` and `.setAttribute('checked') = true;`.

Comment: Thank you John.... I will certainly review that as I feel the answer is in there somewhere. Thanks!!!!